Kotlin project is not correctly loaded after IntelliJ update
Good morning,
I updated my intellij and since then my kotlin projects in micronaut won't load properly.
When I click somewhere it gives me popup: Cannot find declaration to go to.
Root Application.class is not loaded so I also have red cross on Application start button in intellij but I am able to click on green arrow next to that button and run project normally.
I have already tried to:

restart intellij
remove .idea directories and reload projects
invalidate caches and reload projects
reinstall intellij
reinstall JDK

Any idea how to fix it please?

Did you clean/rebuild your project?

1- File | Settings | Plugins | ⚙️ | Disable all downloaded plugins. 2- Close IDE. 3- Remove .idea folder and any .iml files from project root dir. 4- In the IDE, File -> New -> Project from existing sources -> choose your build.gradle file. 5- If it doesn't help, change version of Gradle used to build the project (or add some dependency to build.gradle). 6- Reload the project from the build file or Grade tool window. 7- Also see if clearing Gradle cache helps (.gradle dir in user home dir)

Which version of IntelliJ are you using? Latest versions are very buggy. You should try to downgrade.
